# AngularJS Material Design : Different colors for different tabs in md-tabs

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-material

Is there a way to set different background colors for different tabs in `md-tabs` ?
The default is no color as can be seen in [tabs demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.tabs)

I tried `<md-tabs background-color="green">` but it's not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AngularJS Material design (md) tabs,   `md-tabs` background color is transparent and uses the background color of your main container. Try to add CSS class for `md-tabs` .

> Added background to entire md-tabs

```
md-tabs {
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1; }
```

[image]

> By adding CSS childs to md-tab class, you can see different colors for different tabs.

```
 .md-tab:first-child{background: green; } 
 .md-tab:nth-child(2){background: pink; } 
 .md-tab:nth-child(3){background: blue; }
```

[image]

fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/cxf3otz9/

codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGNEyw

Comment: Yes it works, but I wanted to give different color to different tabs according to some logic..Can we do that ?

Comment: @SaurabhVerma, You can try,but I prefer CSS is the best solution.. I think your question got answer ..

Comment: Since this is angular, you can use `ng-class` or `ng-style` in each of the md-tab.  `<md-tab label='one' ng-class='{"green": isGreenTab(), "blue":isBlueTab()}'>...</md-tab>  <md-tab label='two' ng-style='myStyleFunction()'>...</md-tab>`

Answer (score 2):

Upon evaluating source code, i came to there a way to achieve dynamic content formatting for tab titles. To get that, please write the code as below

```html
<md-tabs>
    <md-tab>
        <md-tab-label>
            <span ng-class="......">
                Title
            </span>
        </md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body>
        content
        </md-tab-body>
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Comment: way better solution!